# 2 port 10Gbe NIC Performance half of expected

Tags: linux, networking, throughput

I'm having trouble getting my expected throughput of a Intel dual port 82599EB 10-Gigabit. I've tried many things and want to know if there's anything I could try that I've missed.

**My hardware configuration**

Two servers with OpenSUSE and a Intel dual port 82599EB 10GbE in each. They are manually configured to static IPs and each port on one machine is connected to a port on the second.

`lspci -vv`

**Throughput Test**

I am using iperf to test. The cards are driving by ixgbe.

On the receiver side, I run

```
iperf -s
```

On the transmitter side:

```
iperf -c 192.168.1.10 -t 20 -B 192.168.1.20
iperf -c 192.168.1.11 -t 20 -B 192.168.1.21
```

And I am now getting around 4.x Gb per interface. If I run only one interface, I get 9.x Gb.

**Configuration Attempts**

I have looked around SE sites, and many other articles. Here are three helpful ones I found.

1. [Network Connectivity — Tuning Intel® Ethernet Adapter throughput performance](http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/cs-025829.htm)
2. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ixgbe.txt
3. http://www.redhat.com/promo/summit/2008/downloads/pdf/Thursday/Mark_Wagner.pdf (PDF)

The two things that really helped:

1. Using jumbo frames by setting the MTU at 9000.
2. Increasing rmem settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

However, I am still running at about 9.5Gbe combined for both channels. I'm thinking I should get 9Gbe or more per channel.

Things I've tried without much success:

- Used ethtool -c to vary interrupt coalescing
- Used ethtool to disable/enable flow control

**Edits as per comments**

To test the CPU utilization I am using `mpstat -P ALL 5`. On the transmitting server, I see
61% utilization.

```
01:12:59 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
...
01:12:59 PM    4    0.00    0.00   61.33    0.00    0.00    9.38    0.00    0.00   29.29
```

That should be okay right? On the receiver I see a max of 30%.

Using lspci, I got the following. I can post the full outputs if needed, but think this shows the required pcie info:

Sender:

```
1: LnkCap: Port #16, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Latency L0 <2us, L1 <32us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
   LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
                    ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
   LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
   DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+
   DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-
   LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-, Selectable De-emphasis: -6dB
Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                     Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
2: LnkCap: Port #16, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Latency L0 <2us, L1 <32us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
   LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
   LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
   DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+
   DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-
   LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-, Selectable De-emphasis: -6dB
   Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
```

Receiver:

```
 1: LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Latency L0 <1us, L1 <8us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
    LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
    LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x4, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+
    DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-
    LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-, Selectable De-emphasis: -6dB
 Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
2: LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Latency L0 <1us, L1 <8us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
   LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
   LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x4, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
   DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+
   DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-
   LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-, Selectable De-emphasis: -6dB
   Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
```

5 G/T at x8 should be plenty right?

Comment: `And I am now getting around 4.x Gb per interface. If I run only one interface, I get 9.x Gb.`  Are you sure there are no other bottlenecks and your problem is the network interfaces?  Is your CPU maxed out or something?

Comment: Or your PCI Express bus? https://communities.intel.com/community/wired/blog/2009/06/08/understanding-pci-express-bandwidth

Comment: The PCI bus is a common bottleneck for 10G cards.

Comment: Ah good points! Thanks! I'm a little out of my element here but I think I've provided the correct info. If not, let me know. It seems like 5G/T per second at x8 should be plenty, but I'll keep looking.